# Getting Events per Month using BigQuery within resource limitations

Tags: google-bigquery

I've got Google Analytics exporting it's data to Big Query. It's now got ca. 14 months of data, containing ca. 430m Events. I want to run a query to get the total number of Events per month (e.g. 201701, 201702, etc.).

I wrote a query, but it will only run on a interval of ca. 4 - 6 days. If I make it larger I get the 'Resources exceeded during query execution.' message. Below is my query. Where did I go wrong in formulating this query? Or should I approach this completely differently (just a beginner...)

The query:

```
SELECT
  MonthYear,
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(combinedVisitorId) AS EventCount,
FROM (
  SELECT
    CONCAT(fullVisitorId,"-",STRING(visitId),"-",STRING(hits.hitNumber)) AS combinedVisitorId,
    hits.eventInfo.eventCategory AS EventCategory,
    CONCAT(CAST(YEAR(SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(visitStartTime)) AS STRING), LPAD(CAST(MONTH(SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP(visitStartTime)) AS STRING), 2, '0')) AS MonthYear,
  FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE([XXX:79296192.ga_sessions_], TIMESTAMP("2016-04-01"), TIMESTAMP("2017-05-30"))
  WHERE
    hits.type="EVENT" )
GROUP BY
  MonthYear
ORDER BY
  EventCount DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below - it is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  YearMonth,
  COUNT(DISTINCT combinedVisitorId) AS EventCount
FROM (
  SELECT
    SUBSTR(_TABLE_SUFFIX, 1, 6) AS YearMonth,
    CONCAT(fullVisitorId,"-",STRING(visitId),"-",STRING(hits.hitNumber)) AS combinedVisitorId
  FROM `XXX.79296192.ga_sessions_*`
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20160401" AND "20170530"
  AND hits.type="EVENT" 
)
GROUP BY YearMonth
-- ORDER BY EventCount DESC
```

Note: I left logic for combinedVisitorId as it is assuming this is exactly the way you want to treat visitors
Also, you can combine above into one select statement (without subquery) - but I wrote it this way intentionally to emphasize approach with wildcard usage

Comment: It doesn't run this query: 'Cannot access field type on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, time INT64, hour INT64, ...>> at [10:12]'. Did some furthger experimentation, found out that the trick is COUNT(DISTINCT )

Answer (score 1):

It's highly recommended that you use the [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) version in BigQuery. If you want to compute the total events, this might do the trick for you:

```
SELECT
  SUM((SELECT COUNTIF(hits.type = 'EVENT') FROM UNNEST(hits) hits)) total_events,
FORMAT_DATE("%B", PARSE_DATE("%Y%m%d", date)) month
FROM `project_id.dataset_id.ga_sessions*`
WHERE
1 = 1
AND CASE WHEN (REGEXP_CONTAINS(_table_suffix, 'intraday') AND REGEXP_EXTRACT(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)') BETWEEN "20170606" AND "20170606" ) THEN TRUE
  WHEN (NOT REGEXP_CONTAINS(_table_suffix, 'intraday') AND REGEXP_EXTRACT(_table_suffix, r'.*_(.*)') BETWEEN "20160605" AND "20170605") THEN TRUE END
GROUP BY month
```

I tested with an entire year here and it processed in around 30 seconds. Notice though that if you use more than a year then data will be grouped in the same month.